# Variational Problem of slow steady flow of viscuous fluid in 2D

Tags: fluid-mechanics, finite-element-method, fluid

I have a Problem with a transformation.

The energy function is the following:

$$I(u_1,u_2,P)=\int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}) u_{i,j}-Pu_{i,i} dx_1 dx_2 - \int_R f_i u_i dx_1dx_2 +\int _S t_iu_idS$$

where

$u_{i,j}=\frac{du_i}{dx_j}$ and Einstein's summation convention is applied (sum over repeating indices).

The task is to compute the variation $\delta I=0$

In the result sheet they do following transformation, which I do not understand:

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1}I(u_1,u_2,P)&=\int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[(\delta u_{i,j} + \delta u_{j,i})u_{i,j}+(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}) \delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...]\\
\tag{2}I(u_1,u_2,P)&=\int_R [\mu(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i})\delta u_{i,j}dx_1 dx_2 +[...]
\end{align}$$

Comment: What does $\delta$ represent in this case? Is it a number arbitrarily close to zero (i.e. a scalar)?

Comment: In any case I think this is more a math question than an engineering one, even though the math is being applied to an engineering problem.

Comment: $\delta$ is a an arbitrary number close to zero, yes. I might try it in the math section then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

As $I= f(u_1,u_2)$ it follows that $\{i,j\}=1,2$

\begin{align}
\tag{1} u_{ij}\delta u_{ji}+ u_{ji}\delta u_{ij}=& \sum_i \sum_j (u_{ij}\delta u_{ji}+ \delta u_{ij}u_{ji})  \\
\tag{2} =&u_{11}\delta u_{11}+ u_{12}\delta u_{21}+u_{21}\delta u_{12}+u_{22}\delta u_{22}+ \\ &\delta u_{11}u_{11}+ \delta u_{12} u_{21}+\delta u_{21} u_{12}+\delta u_{22} u_{22} \\
=&2u_{11}\delta u_{11}+ 2u_{12}\delta u_{21}+2u_{21}\delta u_{12}+2u_{22}\delta u_{22}\\
=&2u_{ij}\delta u_{ji}
\end{align}

Therefore:

\begin{align}
\tag{1}I(u_1,u_2,P)&=\int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[(\delta u_{i,j} + \delta u_{j,i})u_{i,j}+(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}) \delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...]
\\ &= \int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[\delta u_{i,j}u_{i,j} + \delta u_{j,i}u_{i,j}+u_{i,j}\delta  u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}\delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...]
\\ &= \int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[2u_{i,j}\delta  u_{i,j}+  \delta u_{j,i}u_{i,j}+  u_{j,i}\delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...] 
\\ &= \int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[\delta u_{i,j}u_{i,j} + \delta u_{j,i}u_{i,j}+u_{i,j}\delta  u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}\delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...]
\\ &= \int_R [\frac{\mu}{2}[2u_{i,j}\delta  u_{i,j}+ 2u_{j,i}\delta  u_{i,j}] dx_1 dx_2 +[...] 
\\ &=\int_R [\mu(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i})\delta u_{i,j}dx_1 dx_2 +[...]
\end{align}